# How am I supposed to move only Gizmo when in Edit mode?

Tags: axis, transform-orientation, gizmo

Yes.. I know cursor to origin funtion with 3D cursor.

but i can't find way to **only changing pivot in Edit mode.**

I want move Only Gizmo in edit mode... like zbrush transform tool.

There is no snap menu in right click.

Is this situation need 3D cursor use?

Do you have Any other Idea?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly... You can easily solve this using the 3d cursor...

First be sure that you set the pivot point to the 3d cursor (in object mode):

[image: Pivot point]

Back in edit mode you select the edge where you want the center of rotation and hit Shift+S to set the 3d cursor to that edge:

[image: Set 3d cursor]

Problem solved, if your cursor is at the right place you can rotate everything around that point:

[image: rotate around 3d cursor]

Comment: It's very useful. It's surprisingly simple, but I couldn't find a solution anywhere. Thank you for your kind and detailed explanation. I'm impressed with your technique. Happy Blending sir :)